# Show that $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt -x +1 <0,\: x>1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I made the following attempt but it did not feel convincing. I also learned afterward that differentiation is not allowed across inequalities.

The original expression on the LHS is equivalent to

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{1}^{x}\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}-1\right)\:dt = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1$
So the original inequality now says $\sin(x)<x, \: x>1$

But this is a trivial inequality as $\sin(x)$ is bounded by $[-1,1]$.
Therefore, the inequality holds for $x>1$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\int_1^x\frac{\sin t}t-1\,dt$ should be equal to $\frac{\sin x}x-1$. This seems quite false.

Comment: sorry I changed it @Gae.S.

Answer (score 3):

From $$\frac{\sin t}{t}< 1;\;t\ge1 $$
as $x>1$ follows
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt < \int_1^x 1\,dx=x-1$$
thus
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt < x-1\to \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt-x+1< 0$$

Comment: Are there any scenarios where you cannot integrate over the inequality sign?

Comment: @edwindakwesi No. Read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities

Comment: Thanks! @Raffaele

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t} dt -x+1 \implies f(1)=0$$

D.w.r.t. $x$ using Lebnitz:
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}-1 <0, x\in R.$$
So $f(x)$ is decreasing in $x \in R$,  hence
$$ x>1 \implies f(x)<f(1)=0.$$

Comment: I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

The Mean Value Theorem for integrals states that exists a $c \in [1,x]$ such that

$$\frac{1}{x-1}\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin t}{t}dt= \frac{\sin c}{c}<1$$